# Wordpress: Different post from custom post type everyday

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type to display a single quote. Right now I have it set to random, but is it possible to have a WordPress loop that displays a random post but only changes once per day? So basically having a quote of the day post type. I see plugins for a quote of the day but these all pull from an external feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own. The only thing you need is a plugin that displays posts (like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) one), then to make a formula to pick a random post each day and you can set this script to run once per day (usually those type of automations are triggered from visitors).
Useful links:
[Function: get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
[Function: wp_cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

Comment: Also keep in mind that you on stackoverflow it is better to make more specific questions about things you tried and not working rather than something else

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really sure how to handle this and I wasn't able to find anything similar to what I needed. But I found a post scheduling plugin that can essentialy be tweaked to do what I needed: Auto Post Scheduler - https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-post-scheduler/screenshots/

Comment: oh ok it's nice that you found what you need, if you need anything else feel free to comment and maybe my answer will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Found a post scheduling plugin that let me recycle my quotes posts so that they can be randomized daily:

[Auto Post Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-post-scheduler/screenshots/)

Basically, I set the post schedule to 24 hours, set the post type to my custom post type, changed the eligible posts to published, checked randomize, and set the minimum age to 48 hours which I think should prevent the same post from being used two days in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use following code:-

    if ( false === ( $quotes = get_transient( 'random_quote' ) ) ) {


// It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'School',
 'orderby'   => 'rand',
 'limit' => 1,
 'posts_per_page' => '1');
$quotes = get_posts( $args );
set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, DAY_IN_SECONDS);
foreach ( $quotes as $post ) { 
setup_postdata( $post ); 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
 <?php 
  echo $post->post_content;
   ?>
<?php
   } 
wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).